# No Wireless Internet Xubuntu, HP Pavillion Notebook

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu

I dual booted installed Xubuntu on this laptop a while ago, but I haven't used it since I can't get the wireless internet to work (it works fine on windows). I'd really like to fix this problem, how should I go about doing it?

sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: d8:5d:e2:42:38:0f
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.5.3-040503-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:44 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea03fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 07
   serial: 3c:a8:2a:a8:7d:b3
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:36 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe914000-fe914fff memory:fe910000-fe913fff memory:fe900000-fe90ffff
```

EDIT AGAIN: Thanks for the guide. I think I did remove the unsupported kernel, but it's still not working.
Again with the two debian packages in root directory

```
rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.10_all.deb
dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb
```

I think the install went on okay?

```
chris@Chris-crackle:/$ sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb rtlwifi*.deb
[sudo] password for chris: 
(Reading database ... 315543 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11) over (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11) ...
Preparing to unpack rtlwifi-new-dkms_0.10_all.deb ...

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  rtlwifi-new
Version: 0.10
Kernel:  4.4.0-30-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

rtl_pci.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtl_usb.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtlwifi.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


btcoexist.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtl8188ee.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtl8192c-common.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtl8192ce.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtl8192cu.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtl8192de.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtl8192ee.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtl8192se.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtl8723ae.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtl8723be.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


rtl8821ae.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod.........

Backing up initrd.img-4.4.0-30-generic to /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-30-generic.old-dkms
Making new initrd.img-4.4.0-30-generic
(If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-4.4.0-30-generic.old-dkms image)
update-initramfs....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 0.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking rtlwifi-new-dkms (0.10) over (0.10) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11) ...
Setting up rtlwifi-new-dkms (0.10) ...
Loading new rtlwifi-new-0.10 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.4.0-30-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-30-generic
Done.

rtl_pci:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtl_usb.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtlwifi.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

btcoexist.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtl8188ee.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtl8192c-common.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtl8192ce.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtl8192cu.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtl8192de.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtl8192ee.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtl8192se.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtl8723ae.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtl8723be.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

rtl8821ae.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

Backing up initrd.img-4.4.0-30-generic to /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-30-generic.old-dkms
Making new initrd.img-4.4.0-30-generic
(If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-4.4.0-30-generic.old-dkms image)
update-initramfs....

DKMS: install completed.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-30-generic
```

If needed, again this is the result from sudo lshw -C network

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: d8:5d:e2:42:38:0f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.4.0-30-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: 3c:a8:2a:a8:7d:b3
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:36 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe914000-fe914fff memory:fe910000-fe913fff memory:fe900000-fe90ffff
```

There's still absolutely no wifi... perhaps there's something I forgot about?

rfkill list

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

EDIT: It's fixed, following the other answer: sorry for the duplication!
The only thing I would add is that my DNS servers were not configured correctly, which was of course an entirely different issue- hence the confusion. Thank very much Pilot6

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44549/discussion-on-question-by-christopher-turnbull-no-wireless-internet-xubuntu-hp).